# Rsync behind a proxy

Tags: 14.04, ssh, proxy

I'm working behind a proxy with credentials (username/password). The proxy ip is `10.302.34.02` on port `8080`.  My credentials are `myusername` / `mypassword`

On the remote host, ssh is configured on port `12300`.

For using rsync, I installed `connect-proxy`, added my remote host in `.ssh/config`

```
Host toto.be
  ProxyCommand connect -H myusername@10.302.34.02:8080 %h 12300
```

It's working fine.  I can do `ssh toto.be` but it asks me my proxy password.  Ok, it's normal.  But how can I do to store the password somewhere or to put it in the command line ?

I tried

```
ProxyCommand connect -H myusername:mypassword@10.302.34.02:8080 %h 12300
```

But it's not working.  Tells me `Enter proxy authentication password for myusername:mypassword@10.302.34.02`

Also tried with `ssh toto.be << password.file` with same effect (asking me password).

What would be the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`connect` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/connect-proxy.1.html):

```
ENVIRONMENT
   SOCKS5_USER,  SOCKS5_PASSWORD,  HTTP_PROXY_USER,   HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD,
   CONNECT_PASSWORD, LOGNAME, USER
```

So it looks like you could export your proxy password in the `HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD` variable.

Something like:

```
export HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

in `~/.profile`.